# Why do I get remove used apps?

Tags: debian, apt, software-installation, upgrade, kubuntu

I installed Debian 9 with KDE. When I try to remove, install, or upgrade a package I got the following message:

```
$ sudo apt upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done

Calculating upgrade... Done

The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:

  baloo-kf5 ca-certificates-java coinor-libcbc3
  coinor-libcgl1 coinor-libclp1 coinor-libcoinmp1v5 coinor-libcoinutils3v5
  coinor-libosi1v5 default-java-plugin default-jre default-jre-headless
  dolphin dolphin4 fonts-crosextra-caladea fonts-crosextra-carlito
  fonts-lato fonts-linuxlibertine fonts-opensymbol fonts-sil-gentium
  fonts-sil-gentium-basic gir1.2-atspi-2.0 gir1.2-wnck-3.0 gnome-orca
  hyphen-en-us icedtea-8-plugin icedtea-netx icedtea-netx-common
  java-common kaccessible kde-baseapps-bin kde-baseapps-data kde-icons-mono
  kdeaccessibility kdepasswd kdesudo kfind kmag kmousetool kpart-webkit
  libabw-0.1-1 libatk-adaptor libatk-wrapper-java libatk-wrapper-java-jni
  libboost-date-time1.62.0 libboost-filesystem1.62.0
  libboost-iostreams1.62.0 libbrlapi0.6 libcdr-0.1-1 libcgi-fast-perl
  libcgi-pm-perl libclass-accessor-perl libclucene-contribs1v5
  libcmis-0.5-5v5 libcwidget3v5 libdolphinvcs5 libe-book-0.1-1 libeot0
  libetonyek-0.1-1 libexttextcat-2.0-0 libexttextcat-data libfcgi-perl
  libfreehand-0.1-1 libgltf-0.0-0v5 libharfbuzz-icu0 libhsqldb1.8.0-java
  libhyphen0 libio-string-perl libjpeg-turbo-progs libkabc4
  libkf5baloowidgets-bin libkf5baloowidgets5 libkldap4 libkmime4
  libknewstuff2-4 libkonq-common libkonq5-templates libkonq5abi1
  libkonqsidebarplugin4a libkopete4 libkpimidentities4 libkpimtextedit4
  libkpimutils4 libkresources4 liblangtag-common liblangtag1 liblouis-data
  liblouis12 libmediastreamer-base3 libmspub-0.1-1 libmwaw-0.3-3
  libmythes-1.2-0 libodfgen-0.1-1 liborcus-0.11-0 libortp9
  libpagemaker-0.0-0 libparse-debianchangelog-perl libqaccessibilityclient0
  libqca2-plugin-ossl libreoffice libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer
  libreoffice-base libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-base-drivers
  libreoffice-calc libreoffice-common libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw
  libreoffice-help-en-us libreoffice-impress libreoffice-java-common
  libreoffice-kde libreoffice-math libreoffice-report-builder-bin
  libreoffice-sdbc-hsqldb libreoffice-style-galaxy libreoffice-writer
  librevenge-0.0-0 libruby2.3 libservlet3.1-java libsigc++-2.0-0v5
  libsub-name-perl libtidy5 libturbojpeg0 libvisio-0.1-1 libwnck-3-0
  libwnck-3-common libwpd-0.10-10 libwpg-0.3-3 libwps-0.4-4 libxres1
  lp-solve mythes-en-us openjdk-8-jre openjdk-8-jre-headless python3-brlapi
  python3-louis python3-pyatspi python3-speechd python3-uno rake ruby
  ruby-did-you-mean ruby-minitest ruby-net-telnet ruby-power-assert
  ruby-test-unit ruby2.3 rubygems-integration uno-libs3 ure xbrlapi

Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded
```

How do I fix that?

Comment: they were installed as dependencies for packages you removed and are unneded. ``Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

APT classifies installed packages as either automatically installed or manually installed. If a package is marked as automatically installed, it is automatically removed if no manually installed package depends on it.

If you don't use a package directly, it's best if it's marked as automatically installed. The biggest benefit is smoother upgrades if the package is replaced by a package with a different name. In particular, libraries should always be marked as automatically installed, unless they're used by a manually-installed executable. Large applications are often split into several packages and the split changes from time to time, so it's best to keep only the main package and optional functionality that you want as manually installed and let the rest be managed automatically. For example, keep `libreoffice` as manually installed and let the other packages be automatic.

You do need to mark packages as manually installed if you use them, however. Normally this happens automatically because any explicit request to install a package marks it as manually installed, e.g. `apt-get install PACKAGE` or the GUI equivalent.

Use the command `apt-mark` to manipulate the auto/manual package database. `apt-mark auto PACKAGE` declares `PACKAGE` as automatically installed, and `apt-mark manual PACKAGE` declares `PACKAGE` as manually installed.

Run `apt-get autoremove` to remove all packages that are not required by any manually installed package. You get a confirmation prompt, so if this still removes things you want to keep, cancel and declare more packages as manually installed.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a problem.

Run

```
apt-get --purge autoremove
```

and apt will remove all the listed packages.

As the message says, those packages are not needed any more. The `--purge` is entirely optional, but is generally good practice in my opinion. It removes all the package files from the system, including config files.

Comment: but if i did that i will remove all my os apps

Comment: @AhmedAbdalrahman Those packages were all marked as automatically installed. If you want to keep any specific app, you can mark it as manually installed using `apt-mark manual pkgname`. Can you give the example of a package that you are using which would be removed?

Comment: all list of apps i gave above iam using for ex :dolphin

Comment: @AhmedAbdalrahman That's a bit surprising, and shouldn't normally happen. But go through the list and mark the packages that you want to keep as manually installed.